# How to override parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have two classes:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = self.a + 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = 1

print(Child().b)
```

Output is `1` (`0+1`) but I expect to have `2` (`1+1`). How can I achieve such result?

Comment: With the code you are using, 1 is the expected value for `b`, since `Child.__init__()` is first calling `Parent.__init__()` and then setting `self.a`, which happens too late.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `key word argument` to set the value of `a` in the parent class if the argument is not provided:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        if a is None:
            self.a = 0
        self.b = self.a + 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        super().__init__(self.a)

parent = Parent()
child = Child()
print(parent.a, parent.b) 
print(child.a, child.b)
```

#### output:

```
0 1
1 2
```

Another approach could use **class variables**:

```
class Parent(object):
    a = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self.__class__.a
        self.b = self.a + 1

class Child(Parent):
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

parent = Parent()
child = Child()
print(parent.a, parent.b) 
print(child.a, child.b)
```

#### output:

```
0 1
1 2
```

In the above, using class variables, you can entirely do without the `__init__` method in the child class: (this may, or may not be applicable to your real world use case)

```
class Parent(object):
    a = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self.__class__.a
        self.b = self.a + 1

class Child(Parent):
    a = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

assign `a` attribute outside of `Parent.__init__`:

```
class Parent(object):
    a = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = self.a + 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        super().__init__()

print(Child().b)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include an explanation about why this works, and why the original approach failed.

Comment: your code is wrong because every time that parent `__init__` runs `a` attribute will get 0  value that why you get 1 instead of 2

Comment: by calling `super().__init__()` you call the parent `__init__` method

Comment: I meant in your answer, not in the comments. Thank you.